# Error running on XCode "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'GoogleCast.DEVICE_AVAILABLE')"

Tags: ios, react-native, chromecast

I have created a react native application and integrated the react native cast library by following the procedure from link below: 
https://github.com/charliesbox/react-native-google-cast

On running the application on simulator getting the error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'GoogleCast.DEVICE_AVAILABLE')

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0):

Try opening and compiling your react-native project in xcode. I'm guessing it will fail with "'GoogleCast/GoogleCast.h' file not found", in which case you have run into issues [#51](https://github.com/charliesbox/react-native-google-cast/issues/51) and [#21](https://github.com/charliesbox/react-native-google-cast/issues/21).

Fix:

1. In the xcode project navigator, open Libraries/GoogleCase.xcodeproj
2. Choose the GoogleCast target, and Build Settings
3. Add the following to "Framework Search Paths": `$(PROJECT_DIR)/../../../ios/Pods/google-cast-sdk/GoogleCastSDK-2.10.4-Release`